# Change location of tslint.json in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, tslint

I have installed VS 2015 tooling preview 2, in order to have Web code analysis, and perform linting over typescript files, it works well but the problem is that I can not change the location of tslint.json file, I need move it in order to versioning it. The file is create by default in your personal user folder.